# Obtaining Ip address loop for LG Escape 3

Tags: wi-fi

I recently came back home from vacation and attempted to reconnect my phone to my home wifi, only to find myself in a great struggle to get my phone to loacte the IP address. It continues to insist that my connection is poor and conveys the words "avoided poor network". However I know the truth to be quite the opposite for all the other devices in my house connect without issue. But for some reason my phone refuses to obtain it. Need help to resolve this problem please!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've had this problem before forget the wifi the reconnect if that doesn't work tell me

Comment: Yes I've tried that dozens of times it doesn't work. Ive even changed the IP address several times. I'm capable of connecting to wifi other than my home wifi network, and my other devices connect without iissu so Idk where the problem lies